# framework7 xmlresponse to json?

Tags: json, xmlhttprequest, html-framework-7

Hello im new developing using the framework7 in order to make an app, my problem is when i connect to the webservices i send this in my controller.js

```
var postdata = {};
postdata.cantidad = cantidad;
postdata.ultimoValor = ultimoValor;
postdata.id = id;
myApp.showIndicator();

    $$.post('http://192.168.0.134:8090/Test.asmx/GetCliente', {cantidad:'5', ultimoValor:'0',id:'0'}, function (data) {
     myApp.hideIndicator();
     console.log(data);

});
```

The "data" receives the response and the console prints in xml,
and what i need is json to use it.

How can i change it?
i would be great if you can explain me with an example?

Comment: Can you add the response `data`? If I understand correctly, you want to convert the `data` (which is XML) to JSON format?

Comment: Has your issue been solved?